# Unwanted grey borders below divs (Chrome Android)

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, border

I've been trying to fix this bug for days, yet I didn't find a single solution. 
On certain levels of zoom (even on my phone with default zoom) I can see grey borders below some divs. I've been trying to fix this with A LOT of options including:

```
box-shadow
margin-bottom
outline: none
```

... and some other ones which I don't even remember anymore

The issue can be seen here. 
[PICTURE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywszU.jpg)
It's visible on the top of the triangle.

The whole code is available here:
https://noobish.eu/beta/

Comment: Marek, for your triangles, you are nesting 2 elements, one background, one white triangle on top. That causes the problem. You need to remove the background one and make the triangle position absolute and a bit overlapping

Comment: Just to try to explain myself better: right now you have 4 layers: a blue background, then on top a white background, then a blue background again and finally a white triangle. You need to remove the middle blue background, or else you see sometimes that bit of border - it shouldn't, but rendering glitches. You should also overlap the triangle a bit to ensure no more issues

Comment: I'll try to play with this solution when I wake up the next morning. Aladin's solution seemed to fix the issue (the updated one), thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your website (BTW great design) and i think i figured out a solution for your issue. You need to add a negative margin to the triangle to cover the space:

```
.white_triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 130px 50vw 0 50vw;
    border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
    margin-top: -5px; /* Here's the addition */
}
```

**Update:**

The margin-top solution seems to be buggy, so I found another solution, which would require adding a before element on top of the border. Here's the code:

```
.white_triangle_container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

This is how it looks: https://i.gyazo.com/25db9e4b9db16c42d374cfd78b47736d.png

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I already had a -1px margin-top in there, adding 4 more pixels didn't really help, unfortunately. :( Also, I seem to have this issue in between other divs such as .prace and .reversemountain
And by the way, thank you for rating my design, I appreciate it!

Comment: It works. The issue was that you had written the margin-bottom property incorrectly. The way you have it now is margin-top: -1p if i remember correctly. Replace it with this and let me know if it works. I did already implement the code, and it worked for me.

Comment: I copied the code, refreshed the page. (It's on the web now), yet I can still see the line. I even tried incognito mode on my phone. I can only see these lines on my phone.

Comment: I checked too. With some pixel values it seems to work, with some not, but it is a subpixel rendering accuracy problem, so that is expected. If you zoom it at different levels, sometimes it appear some not

Comment: I understand. Since there aren't any gradients or stuff like that, is it possible to remove these somehow by using just one color?

Comment: Yes. I tried with -11px now and it seems to work: https://gyazo.com/4e5a5696a2f24f0410d8e17615854821

Comment: This seems to work. However, when I want to fix other elements with this issue, this one bugs out again.

Comment: @MarekFarkaš Found a better solution! Checkout my updated answer!

Comment: Your updated solution seemed to work after a bit of playing with the settings! Thanks!